# HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name returns always empty

Tags: asp.net, authentication, cookies, forms-authentication, session-cookies

Hi I am using forms authentication in my application to authenticate super and non super user.

```
<system.web>
    <authentication mode="form" >
     <forms loginUrl = "~/login.aspx"  defaultUrl = "~/sharepage/desktop.aspx "  slidingExpiration = "true" protection"None" timeout = "2880" cookieless="UseCokkies"></forms >
    <authentication
</system.web>

< authorization >
  <allow users = "*"/>
</ authorization >
```

I have one session class object which I have serialize and compressed and store into `StrPriUserDetails` variable
Then m saving this randon charatcer string "hH249Gjlsdpiencsd930jfm8347..." in Cookies

```
FormAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(StrPriUserDetails ,false)
System.Web.Security.FormAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(StrPriUserDetails ,false)
```

I am using HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name to get the user session variable when the web application is in use.

```
HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name
```

Now, when I publish the web application, it comes back blank. 
Does anyone know why this is and how to fix it?Am I missing something?

Comment: Just to verify, did you log into the website? if "HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated" comes back FALSE, then Identity.Name will be blank.

Comment: `cookieless="UseCokkies"` doesn't sound right.